# how to get touch screen event when screen is off?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is that it is possible to receive events when the screen is Off, because I want to wake alarm clock app that will turn the screen on and wait for a user action, and also that will display hours if the user touch the screen
Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. What you want is something like you would like to make a call while the device is not turned on.

Comment: It makes sense to disable touch sensors :/

Answer (score 0):

When the screen is turned off, it also turns the touch sensors off. The thing you asked is impossible. You can still make the screen's contents black and dim the backlight. (The screen will then still be on.) Or, you could use some of the device's buttons (not Home, Back or Menu because they can be virtual in Android 4).